# No module named apparmor. Why?

Tags: debian, package-management, apparmor, module

Context : I installed (manually) the apparmor-utils and apparmor-profiles and apparmor-utils,  since when trying

```
apt-get install apparmor-utils apparmor-profiles
```

can't find the packages.

```
aa-status
```

works as usual.
I also did

```
sed -i -e 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&security=apparmor /' /etc/default/grub
```

to enable it.
However when I try

```
aa-genprof
```

it says:

```
import apparmor.aa as apparmor ... No module named apparmor
```

What is the problem if I already installed it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Which version of Debian do you use? From where did you get the packages you installed manually and which version exactly did you install? Did you run `apt-get update` before `apt-get install ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing apparmor package which will provide that python module:

```
sudo apt install python3-apparmor
```

If you can’t install that, you need to fix your repository configuration; you will then also be able to install the Debian AppArmor packages.

Comment: This is also a problem I encountered. I have tried updating it with ```sudo apt upgrade -y``` but it still doesn't work and can't find the package.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was a problem with the repositories. I had enabled some that weren't able to find those packages. Once I changed them, it worked.